# How to save form without validation

Tags: django, validation, django-forms

I want that my users can fill a post form partially, save as draft and then edit, finish and publish it. So the draft can have some required (text) fields empty. However I want the fields secure to store in the database (so, no special character, etc).

What's the best (or a good way) way to do this?

I think these solutions:

1) make two different models, one with `required=False` fields or

2) fill the empty text field with a temporary string ('draft'), then delete it e redraw as needed while edit, publish, save the draft. Or

3) deactivate the validation (novalidation, I'm not sure this works).

or what else?

I'm looking to the second way because the first I think will give me problems to manage two models and the third maybe is not secure.

PS I'm using ajax to call the views.

Comment: I suggest you to put all your fields optionals, and an extra boolean field for when is finished, so when you try to save with this field in true, then you validate all.

Comment: Thank you but I have a doubt: I'm not sure to have an use for the extra boolean field: sometimes I want to publish a post with some field empty (for example a translation field) and in this case that field should be true or false? How I'm supposed to use it? to remember me that I have to translate a field or to allow pubblication? or?

Comment: what I mean is to use this field in False while is draft, when the user wants to published set this field to True, in that case you have to validate whatever you need.